# Prove or disprove that if $a = bm + r$, then $\gcd(a,m) = \gcd(a,r)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove that if $a = bm + r$, then $\gcd(a,m) = \gcd(a,r)$

I tried using the fact of GCD's in my calculations to get the fact that d|b and d|a-bm then try to compare that with the gcd(a,m) by solving for b and r, but I can't seem to get anything realistic.

what I did try doing is find the the equality $a-bm =\frac{ (a-r)}{b }$to actually get m=r for gcd purposes..but I wouldn't be able to tell my professor that that was actually mathematics.

Comment: any constraints on a,b,m,r?

Comment: None at all for this question

Comment: can r be zero then? edit: counterexample below works

Comment: Set $$a=4,b=2,m=8,r=-12$$ I think you meant $$(a,m)=(bm+r, m)=(bm+r-b\cdot m,m)=(r,m)$$

Comment: this is a contradiction since $r\ge 0$

Comment: @Jonas12 then you can use r = 0, for a = 12, b = 2 and m = 6 - but OP stated no constraints on r

Comment: Hey guys, please reread the question. I typed the question wrong! This one is more interesting.

Comment: @Matthew then I believe a counterexample still exists from the numbers i provided - are you sure there aren't additional constraints?

Comment: The question I wrote is literally the only information provided.

Comment: @Matthew Then for $$r = 0, a = 12, b = 2,m = 6$$ $$\gcd(a,m) = 6$$ and $$\gcd(a,r) = 12$$, so the statement is false

Answer (score 3):

Let $\alpha=\gcd(a,m)$ and $\beta=\gcd(b,r)$ and since $\alpha$ divides $a$ and $m$ then it divides $a-bm=r$ so $\alpha$ divides $a$ and $r$ so $\alpha\le \beta$. By the same method we prove that $\beta$ divides $a$ and $m$ so $\beta\le\alpha$. Conclude.

**Edited** The question was edited  and now the result isn't true and a counterexample is
$$a=32,\; b=5,\; m=6,\; r=2$$
and 
$$\gcd(a,m)=6\ne 2=\gcd(a,r)$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I posted the question wrong! Can you have a look at the new one? This one is more interesting.

Comment: This answer still works! What Sami did was to prove that $\alpha\le \beta$ and $\beta\le\alpha$ wich implies $\alpha =\beta$. In this answer, why $\alpha\le \beta$? Note that $\beta=\gcd(b,r)$, this means that, if you can find any other common divisor between $b$ and $r$, it would be less than or equal to $\beta$. In this case $\alpha$ divides $b$ and $r$ (why?). This implies that $\alpha$ is a common divisor of $b$ and $r$. Because $\beta$ is the greatest common divisor, then $\alpha\le \beta$

Comment: @AndrewGSM It is not clear to me what Sami claims to be proving. Hopefully he will elaborate.

Comment: @BillDubuque I edited my answer according to the edited question.

Comment: @Sami But what were you claiming to prove in the first place?